# Instalar nueva versión de Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Estoy intentando instalar la v2.387.3 de Jenkins

Para ello, he desinstalado (desde el Panel de Control de Windows) la anterior versión que tenía (la v2.319.1)
El caso es que al desinstalar esta última, me ha guardado todos los jobs, plugins, configuraciones, etc... que tenía en ella, y al arrancar la nueva versión, me sale todo eso.

En este momento, lo que hay no me sirve de nada, porque ni puedo usar esos jobs antiguos (porque dice que está todo desactualizado), ni puedo usar la nueva versión (porque no ha instalado nada de ella).

Entiendo que no se pueden tener 2 versiones de Jenkins en el mismo ordenador, ¿no?

Me gustaría poder usar la nueva versión nueva, pero mantener (al menos poder guardar en algún sitio) los datos de los jobs anteriores.

¿se puede hacer esto?

Gracias